# raspberry pi - wall mount display / passanger information system

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

When raspberry pi boots up I want to do 2 tasks

1. launch it to full screen chromium browser 30 sec's
2. play some video after 30 sec's and once's video get over relaunch browser to full screen.

Repeat this 2 step's continuously, how ever I have accomplished to start web page at boot up with following thing,

> sudo geany /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

```
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@chromium-browser --disable-translate --kiosk --incognito file:///home/pi/Desktop/BusInformation.html
```

Now next thing, I wrote a sample shell for testing, which i have initialized it in crontab.

> fullscreen.sh

```
`/usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-translate --kiosk --incognito file:///home/pi/Desktop/PIS_DisplayMessages/Dept.html` &
sleep 20;
sudo pkill -f chromium

`omxplayer /home/pi/Desktop/FivStar.mp4`

`/usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-translate --kiosk --incognito file:///home/pi/Desktop/PIS_DisplayMessages/Dept_Hindi.html` &
sleep 20;
sudo pkill -f chromium
```

After boot up, raspberry fails to start browser, only play video.

If add this shell in

> sudo geany /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

That time also it fails to start the browser.

Comment: Have you considered the [magic mirror](https://magicmirror.builders/)? Although this is using a mirror, there are somethings which you have in common. Such as; - Launching a full screen browser to display data. - Pulling in information from 3pp sites to display. The SW is available on the site for download as open source. I don't know if it can do the video you want, but their might be a plug-in available to help you. Else, you can edit the SW to your needs or build your own plugin